# Python33 - Running one function in multiple threads/processes to speed it up

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, list, multiprocessing

I am using a `while True` loop to add things to the list every loop, and I am calculating things about the whole list every time it iterates. I am adding new things to the list with a factor of 1.1x, so if the list is length 10 at the start, it will be 11 after the first iteration.

The calculation part is basically an if-else maze which numbers will pass through, and things about other numbers in the list will change and new ones will be added. There are not a lot of function calls, I tried having all code in the same function.

This is the core code:

```
...variables to record data
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
while True:
    for item in a_list:
        ...calculate things
        ...compare things
        ...add new things to list
        ...store data in another list/file
```

What is the best way to make this function run faster?

**TLDR:** I have one function and I want to run it in multiple threads/processes to speed it up.

EDIT:

I also have to note that I have thought of dividing the list into two/four when the length reaches 100,000, and iterating over those lists each in it's own thread. I am not sure how to implement this though.

EDIT2:

I am running this program in the background now, it has been running for about three hours and it's on iteration 131 with the list being 400,000 long.

Comment: Its not the while loop or the for loop, its probably your calculations and the other code. You will get a better answer if you post your calculation code.

Comment: @enginefree Well, it's basically calculating the list growth each `while` iteration, and in the list iteration it will make choices through a nested if-else maze based on the number, and it will also interact and change other numbers in the list. In some parts in the if-else maze, it will add new numbers to the list, and will also store information in variables for research.

Comment: @enginefree I'll also have to add it makes some function calls, with the most substantial one being a function which will generate a new number based on previous ones.

Comment: Threads will only slow down your code. The only thing that you could do is to use multiple processes, but in this case you must be sure that the overhead of the communications is small.

Comment: @Bakuriu Please elaborate.

Comment: You are doing CPU-bound work there, correct? In this case CPython's GIL(Global Interpreter Lock) wont allow your code to use the CPUs concurrently at all, hence threading will only slow down your program. Using multiple processes solves this issue, but communications between processes are *slow*, so you must be careful to minimize them to obtain big gains in speed. Try to avoid shared state as much as possible, otherwise a lot of time will be spent in acquiring/releasing the shared objects.

Comment: @Bakuriu is it possible to share that same list across multiple processes, and constantly modify things in it, or will that be too many communications?

Comment: @IPDGino It is possible(see `Manager` class of the `multiprocessing` module for example), but I believe it will be too slow. (It should be pretty easy to try, so go on and try before ruling this out). Instead of accessing single elements of a list the subprocesses could work on bigger chunks, thus reducing the overhead per item.